# Is this clang optimization a bug?

Tags: c, optimization, clang, compiler-optimization

I ran into an interesting issue when compiling some code with -O3 using clang on OSX High Sierra. The code is this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h> /* for CHAR_BIT */
#include <stdio.h> /* for printf() */
#include <stddef.h> /* for size_t */

uint64_t get_morton_code(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t z)
{
    /* Returns the number formed by interleaving the bits in x, y, and z, also
     * known as the morton code.
     *
     * See https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveTableO
bvious.
     */
    size_t i;
    uint64_t a = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(x)*CHAR_BIT; i++) {
        a |= (x & 1U << i) << (2*i) | (y & 1U << i) << (2*i + 1) | (z & 1U << i)
 << (2*i + 2);
    }

    return a;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("get_morton_code(99,159,46) = %llu\n", get_morton_code(99,159,46));
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling this with `cc -O1 -o test_morton_code test_morton_code.c` I get the following output:

```
get_morton_code(99,159,46) = 4631995
```

which is correct. However, when compiling with `cc -O3 -o test_morton_code test_morton_code.c`:

```
get_morton_code(99,159,46) = 4294967295
```

which is wrong.

What is also odd is that this bug appears in my code when switching from `-O2` to `-O3` whereas in the minimal working example above it appears when going from `-O1` to `-O2`.

Is this a bug in the compiler optimization or am I doing something stupid that's only appearing when the compiler is optimizing more aggressively?

I'm using the following version of clang:

```
snotdaqs-iMac:snoFitter snoperator$ cc --version
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) is really helpful in catching such mistakes:

```
$ clang -fsanitize=undefined -O3 o3.c
$ ./a.out
o3.c:19:2: runtime error: shift exponent 32 is too large for 32-bit type 'unsigned int'
get_morton_code(99,159,46) = 4294967295
```

A possible fix would be replacing the `1U`s with `1ULL`, an `unsigned long long` is at least 64 bit and can be shifted that far.

Comment: Woah! That is freaking awesome!

Answer (score 8):

When `i` is 15 in the loop, `2*i+2` is 32, and you are shifting an `unsigned int` by the number of bits in an `unsigned int`, which is undefined.

You apparently intend to work in a 64-bit field, so cast the left side of the shift to `uint64_t`.

A proper `printf` format for `uint64_t` is `get_morton_code(99,159,46) = %" PRIu64 "\n"`. `PRIu64` is defined in the `<inttypes.h>` header.

Comment: Thanks! I think the `2*i` is correct. You pick up an extra factor of `i` since the bit you are masking in is already in the `i`th place.

Comment: `PRId64` is `d`'s counterpart. You should use `PRIu64` instead for `uint64_t`.

Comment: @a3f: Thanks, fixed. And I would recommend `PRIx64`, for this, since it makes it hugely easier to see the bits.

Comment: can you quote standard that say it's undefined behavior to overflow on an unsigned with shift ? I'm very curious, as overflow on unsigned is defined I don't understand why with shifting it would not.